# Connect to Local Webservice from Mobile app

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services

I need to make an application where a mobile web app can connect to a local web service in a LAN.  For example, several locations are running this web service on their own local server. When someone with the mobile app comes into the location they can open it up and it will somehow be able to connect to that local webservice through WiFi.  The mobile app won't know the IP of that webservice ahead of time.  Any thought on how to go about this?  This will be a .NET webservice and HTML5 app but I don't think that matters.

Comment: You can include it as a configuration option in app settings, or have them register with a centralized server to pull down the server location.

Comment: Ultimately you need to end up having your app understanding what IP they need to connect to at whatever location. How you do that is the issue. If you don't want users to have to manually update the IP, then you would likely configure it with a proxy that would properly route the request depending on the location, or possibly the best bet would be to have an externally available that your app could query based on the location in order to find out what the latest IP is for that location.

Which is pretty much what @mason just said above ;-)

Comment: Thanks.  That was the only think I could think of but wanted to see if there was another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you will probably have to make it configurable by the user as the will ultimately need the address of the server.

There is however another approach that you can take. Develop a small multicast/udp service that broadcasts the web service address every 10-30 seconds. In your android application register a broadcast receiver that responds to the network connectivity status and runs in the background.

This service on the Android service will pick up the address from the UDP broadcasts and then configure the application.

Comment: This isn't an Android app.  It's an HTML5 app running on the mobile browser, would this still work?